# Creating multiple instances of react native app in the same android app (without redux)

Tags: android, react-native

I have an activity which has a Fragment and React Native is added in a `ReactRootView` inside the fragment. I've added the `ReactInstanceManager` as a singleton in the app and attaching it to the rootview and starting the app using the `startApplication()` method of `ReactRootView` class. It all works well when only one instance of the Activity is present.

I have a flow where I need to start a new instance of the same activity. This time the React Native app does load and I can see the render function being called for the second Activity, but instead of updating the view of the second one it updates the view of the first activity which is attached.

I'm calling all the lifecycle methods for the `ReactInstanceManager` in the attached fragment and the `onPause()` and `onResume()` callbacks are being called. I'm really stuck here and don't know what to do. I've tried creating a new instance of the ReactInstanceManager but it's not helping either.

This is the flow I'm trying to achieve:
***ReactFragment -> OtherActivity -> ReactFragment***

I need the Activity with the ReactFragment to have different instances  and load the react app again in the second one, which it does, but the `render()` function updates the first instance instead of the second one.

Instantiating `ReactInstanceManager`:

```
    public synchronized ReactInstanceManager getReactInstanceManager(Activity activity) {
    if (reactInstanceManager == null) {
        reactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(activity.getApplication())
                .setJSMainModulePath("index")
                .setJSBundleFile("index.android.bundle")
                .addPackages(Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                        new FabricPackage(),
                        new MainReactPackage(),
                        new MSREventBridgePackage(),
                        new Interactable()
                ))
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();
    }
    return reactInstanceManager;
}
```

Adding the `ReactInstanceManager` to the `ReactRootView` class and starting the application:

```
     mReactInstanceManager = ReactApplicationManager.getInstance().getReactInstanceManager(getActivity());
     mReactRootView.startReactApplication(
            mReactInstanceManager,
            REACT_MODULE,
            null);
```

Calling all the lifecycle methods for `ReactInstanceManager`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onHostResume(getActivity(), (DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler)getActivity());
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onHostPause(getActivity());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onHostDestroy(getActivity());
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using Redux? If so, are both your components connected to the same store?

Comment: see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6410. may helpful